# Tabbed User Interface

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am looking to implement a tabbed user interface but I am finding that all my code is stuck in one aspx file. This is becoming a mess really fast and all the tutorials show tabs in this way.

Are there any ways to implement a tabbed user interface with each tab being a separate aspx file or do most people do a lot of extra coding to make their tabs performance better such as using update panels...only loading data on the active tab...

I just cant imaging once this project gets large enough and I have 30 tabs that they all exist on one aspx file.

Other than breaking up the tabs into groups any other suggestion on how the professionals would handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load your content via AJAX:

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

Refer to the example on in the docs.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
    <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
</ul>
```

The URL from the `<a>` tag specifies the source for the tab content.

Comment: I seen this however this does not answer my question.

Comment: I don't understand your question then. I thought you were asking how to have separate aspx pages for each tab.

Comment: wow sorry it was me I did not understand your answer I should have looked closer. Thanks